# Using IF Statement to return value from another field of the same attribute table with Field Calculator

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, expression, if-statement

I am trying to get the field calculator within QGIS 3.20 to create a new field (`"*NewField*"`) that matches text in another field (`"name1"`) when a condition (`= 1`) is met in another field (`"LabelNUM"`).

So far, I have tried:

```
IF("LabelNUM" = 1, "name1", NULL)

IF("LabelNUM" IS '1', "name1", NULL)

IF("LabelNUM" = 1, "*NewField*" = "name1", NULL)
```

But none of these have worked.

Here is my attribute table:

[image: Attribute Table]

For example, from this image I want a new field to display 'Ashlett Creek' for the row with the ID: 441566, and *NULL* for all the others.

Comment: When asking a question, instead of "none of these have worked" state what the result was and how it differs from what you want to achieve. Showing us also you field calculator dialog window would also help to identify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two of your three expressions is correct and should produce the correct result: a copy of the text in field `"name1"` in case field `"LabelNum"` has value 1 and empty (`NULL`) otherwise. Be sure to set `Output field type` to Text (string) and set a `Output field length` long enough for yours strings - see screenshot:

[image]