# Using IF statement in Field Calculator to write values into new field based on another field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, if-statement

For some QGIS-OSM import tasks, I'm trying to create a new attribute field for objects based on existing attributes in the Field Calculator.

In short, for all the objects with the existing field `CLASS` having the value `42211`, I want a new field called `building` and to have the value of those objects as `home`, and for all `CLASS = 42261` I want `building = yes`.
Other values can stay as `NULL`.

I used [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403671/using-if-statement-to-return-value-from-another-field-of-the-same-attribute-tabl) as a guide, but all I'm getting is "Expression is invalid" with this expression:

```
case
    IF("CLASS" = 42211, "building" = "home", NULL) 
    IF("CLASS" = 42261, "building" = "yes", NULL)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing 2 different syntaxes.

- `if()` allows a single condition, with a TRUE/FALSE output
- `CASE WHEN` allows multiple conditions, but is a bit more verbose

Using `if()`, you can write your query with nested ifs :

```
if ("CLASS" = 42211, 'home', if ("CLASS" = 42261, 'yes', NULL))
```

But it would be more flexible using `CASE WHEN` like this :

```
CASE
WHEN "CLASS" = 42211 THEN 'home'
WHEN "CLASS" = 42261 THEN 'building'
ELSE NULL
END
```

Anyway, in both those ways, the output field has to be filled inside the field calculator settings, as seen in this screenshot (UI in french, but this shouldn't be hard to match) :
[image]